# What are all the possible fixes to the error 'Unable to create directory /wp-content/uploads' when trying to upload images in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, file-upload, permissions

I am getting the following error

> Unable to create directory /wp-content/uploads. Is its parent
>   directory writable by the server?

whenever I try to upload images via the Media tab in Wordpress. I am running on a LAMP setup, specifically on Ubuntu with Wordpress version 4.1.1. I'm working on a localhost site otherwise I would provide a link. I've tried all of the solutions that I have found and so far, none of them have worked.

Things I've tried:

- I recursively changed the permissions of the wp-content folder to 777. (I'll downgrade the permissions to a safer setting after this problem is solved.)
- I changed the group owner of the uploads folder to www-data as seen in [this solution](http://cycentum.miraiserver.com/en/Memos/WordPressPermission.html) so that Apache would have group ownership of the folder.
- I deleted the .htaccess file and resaved the permalinks setting.
- I tried changing the uploads path in wp-config.php.

I asked this [same question](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-create-directory-wp-contentuploads-4?replies=3) on the Wordpress forums and received one answer that I tried, but it didn't work for me. At this point I have no clue what to try. If anybody has an idea of what I need to do to get this to work it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When permissions or files become corrupted, it can often be worth re installing the WP core files from scratch, I recommend downloading the WP files from the codex site.

We often help clients with support via hangouts, please look us up at https://plus.google.com/+Myfavoritewebdesigns https://plus.google.com/+JoshuaJacoby/posts

Thanks!
My Favorite Web Designs
Joshua Jacoby
1006 N. 92nd Circle
Mesa, AZ 85207
Office: 480-335-1330

**AZ WordPress Designer**

Comment: This should be a comment